# How does the "most active" tab under each site work in Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

I have seen a section called "most active" under "top beta users" which is related to users of that particular beta site. How does this work?

[image]

Comment: This is a typical support question as you ask how a certain feature works. Why did you change to discussion? If you want to ask something different e.g. "why is it this way" then better do that in separate question.

Comment: Sorry, would you consider responding on my answer or accepting it if it suits you?

Answer (score 1):

It sorts by the number of posts (answers+questions) users posted.

Most active user = a user who posted most posts on the site, least active = a user who posted the smallest amount of posts on the site (users who didn't post at all are excluded).